# Python if statement not functioning

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print("Hello World")
myName = input("What is your name?")
myVar = input("Enter a number:")
if myName == "MZ" or myVar != 0:
    print("MZ is great")
elif myName == "MV":
    print("MV is ok")
else:
    print("Hello World")
```

No matter what I input as name *myName* or number *myVar*, it always prints `MZ is great`.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: No, probably a string. Because that's what `input()` returns. And since the comparison is (in)equality, no exception is raised.

Comment: Parentheses are not necessary on the if statement, by the way

Answer (score 4):

First off, MZ is great!

This happens because of `or myVar != 0`. Since `input()` returns a string (in Python 3) and you compare it to a number, `myVar` will never be equal to the number 0. You should do something like:

```
myVar = int(input("Enter a number:"))
```

You should probably also catch `ValueError` in case the user types a bad number.

Comment: Thankyou Allen and kichik. Tried both solutions and both work fine. MZ is great! :)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if(myName == "MZ" or myVar != 0)
```

to

```
if(myName == "MZ" or myVar != "0")
```

User input is string by default.

Comment: Thankyou Allen and kichik. Tried both solutions and both work fine. MZ is great! :)